# Add title in chart Studio R automaticly

Tags: r

How I can edit this studio R code so that the title changes automaticly if I change the ticker from yahoo finance. The following code calculates the maximum drawdown of a stock. I only change the yahoo ticker symbol. But now I want, when I change the yahoo ticker symbol the title of the chart should correspond with the same ticker symbol. Until now I have to change every time the title if I change the ticker symbol. Thanks for any help

```
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.quadprog)
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
library(caTools)
library(quantmod)
library(timeSeries)
library(astsa)
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(tibble)
library(corrplot)
library(tidyr)

# Get risk-free rate (1 month T-Bond rate) from FRED
rf <- getSymbols('DGS1MO', src = 'FRED', auto.assign = FALSE)

# ticker for SBUX Index
ndx_symbol <- 'SBUX'


ndx <- getSymbols(ndx_symbol, from = "1950-01-01", auto.assign = FALSE)

str(ndx)

any(is.na(ndx))
dailyReturn

ndx_daily <- to.daily(ndx)

ndx_returns <- Return.calculate(ndx_daily$ndx.Adjusted)
ndx_returns <- ndx_returns[(-1),]
names(ndx_returns) <- 'NDX_daily'

plot.zoo(ndx_returns, main = 'SBUX Daily Returns', xlab = 'Date')

chart.Drawdown(ndx_returns, plot.engine = "ggplot2") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = -0.15, size = 1) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, lineheight = 0.5)) +
            scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits=c(-1,0))+
ggtitle("Drawdowns of Starbucks, monthly data",
          subtitle = "Black line indicates bear markets")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace

```
"Drawdowns of Starbucks, monthly data"
```

with:

```
paste0("Drawdowns of ",ndx_symbol,", monthly data")
```

Title will become: "Drawdowns of SBUX, monthly data", with SBUX changing to the respective stock symbol.
If you have a df/source that relates each symbol with the respective full company name, a few more code lines could make it so the latter is shown instead.